# Uploading file using fetch in Ionic 6

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with fetch and Ionic 6. It is not sending image data to the server.

The code is as follows:

```
          let formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('photo', pathImage);
          
          fetch(this.MAIN_URL + '/uploadAvatar?token=' + token, { method: 'POST', body: formData})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          })
          .catch(error => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(error));
          })
```

Thing is, the image data is not being sent to the server. The variable pathImage comes from Ionic's Crop plugin, and it is like this:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/(random_number).jpg

I think it is not getting the data from pathImage, but how can I change that? I tried turning pathImage into a blob but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, here is the answer to my question:

```
      let formData = new FormData();
      const file = await Filesystem.readFile({ path: pathImage.split('?')[0] });

      let blob = new Blob([this.fixBinary(atob(file.data))], { type: 'image/jpeg' });

      formData.append('photo', blob);
      
      fetch(this.MAIN_URL + '/uploadAvatar?token=' + token, { method: 'POST', body: formData})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      })
```

Where fixBinary is a function that fixes the binary data coming from the jpg file:

```
  fixBinary (bin: any) {
     var length = bin.length;
     var buf = new ArrayBuffer(length);
     var arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       arr[i] = bin.charCodeAt(i);
     }
     return buf;
  }
```

Now, if I pick and crop a file, the end result is uploaded to the server just fine.